# Watir-webdriver with firefox

Tags: watir-webdriver

I'm working on web-application automation using ruby and ruby's framework watir-webdriver with Firefox v20.0.1, when I use `file_field` function to get the file, it gives the following errors:

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)

Before, I was running same code with Firefox profile is 'default' that time working fine,
and now I changed the Firefox profile is 'new' and getting these errors. Moreover I not able to set the Firefox profile to 'default' on v20.0.1.

Whether it is correct way or not, please help me!

Comment: Please provide relevant Ruby and HTML code. Even better, point us to the page where the problem is reproducible.

Comment: The latest firefox was just released and has caused some problems for all webdriver based  browser drivers (selenium, watir-webdriver, capybara, etc)  ensure you have the very latest webdriver gem

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
gem update webdriver
```

from the command line to ensure you have the latest webdriver code?